How in python can you combine several small PDF files into one, for example in A4 format, as Acrobat does when printing?
I tried PyPDF2 and reportlab, but they seem to want images to be merged, not pdfs This creates only an empty A4:
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape, mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
def combine_small_pdfs(input_paths, output_path):
Create a new PDF in A4 format in landscape orientation
c = canvas.Canvas(output_path, pagesize=landscape(A4))

# Determine the size of small PDF pages (55 mm by 40 mm in millimeters)
small_page_width, small_page_height = 55 * mm, 40 * mm

# Calculate how many small pages fit on one row and column on an A4 page
rows = int(A4[1] / small_page_height)
cols = int(A4[0] / small_page_width)

# Initialize variables for arranging small pages on A4 sheet
x, y = 0, A4[1] - small_page_height

# Load small pages and paste them onto an A4 page
page_index = 0
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        if page_index < len(input_paths):
            pdf_path = input_paths[page_index]

 
            input_pdf = PdfReader(pdf_path)
            page = input_pdf.pages[0]
            c.drawPage(page)

     
            x += small_page_width
            if x >= A4[0]:
                x = 0
                y -= small_page_height
                c.showPage()  

            page_index += 1

  c.save()

input_files = ["temp_barcode_1.pdf", "temp_barcode_2.pdf", "temp_barcode_3.pdf", 
"temp_barcode_4.pdf", "temp_barcode_5.pdf", "temp_barcode_6.pdf"]
output_file = "combined_a4.pdf"
combine_small_pdfs(input_files, output_file)

